# version `libmysqlclient_20.0' not found

Tags: mysql, c, linux

my machine is CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

my code written with c

mysql's version is mariadb

I copy the libmysqlclient.so.20 from /usr/lib64/mysql to /lib64 but fount an error:

version `libmysqlclient_20.0' not found

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the library of the mysql is in /usr/local/mysql,but lsconfig's default path is /usr/lib,so add the

Comment: Incomplete answer. 
So add the what?